# Unrecognized font family 'sans-serif' React-Native

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, fonts

when start app into iOS (Emulator or real device) it throws this error:

"Unrecognized font family 'sans-serif'

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVT71.png (Error)

But in nowhere am using it. I have linked all my fonts in the Into.plist

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa6CN.png (Info.plist)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1HE6.png (Fonts folder)

If i search all the references with 'sans-serif' in the Visual Studio Code, the only place where appears that font its in the index.android.bundle

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lX6H.png (Search result)

That error only happend with the iOS compile, with Android dont have this problem.

Versions:

- Node.js v14.16.1.
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.59.4
- MacOS: 10.15.7
- Xcode: 12.4 (12D4e)

I tried linked the fonts, but dont have the font file to link.

Dont know what to do.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code where you used said font?

Comment: Am not using it. I think maybe some dependancy using it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This has been vexing me for days.